# Why NetUserGetInfo does not give me the users home directory?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, active-directory

i am using netusergetinfo function in my c++ project.

the function works fine.

But it cant give the home directory value.it comes null value.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Probably there is no home directory configured.  What do you see if you use the "net user" command to look at the user account properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SHGetKnownFolderPath` function (with `FOLDERID_Profile`) to get the profile directory for a specified user.

Comment: Minimum support for this function is vista,but i am using xp.

Comment: In XP you can use `SHGetFolderPath`.

Comment: @ Jonathan : actually i need user Organisational Unit(OU),how can i get using NetuserGetinfo function.